# Can I ask about Maptool?

Tags: support, tools

Would a question specifically about maptool functions (i.e. Macros) be off-topic here, given the "tools" and "gm-techniques" tags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. We offer advice on using game-adjacent tools such as [roll20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roll20) or [pcgen](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pcgen).

We had a past question already about maptool to which I've added the [maptool](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maptool) tag.

Comment: Cool, ty. Im glad there's a tag for it now. The past week I've been banging my head on the wall trying to decide whether to finally try here, lol.